# singular matrix and limits

Tags: linear-algebra, limits

I have a block matrix given as $D=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & A\end{bmatrix}$.
If I write $D$ as $D=\begin{bmatrix}\epsilon I & 0\\0 & A\end{bmatrix}$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $\epsilon \to 0$ then I can take its inverse as $D^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\epsilon} I & 0\\
0 & A^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}$ (Note I haven't used the limit yet). 
Then I have the product $x^TD^{-1}x$ where $x$ is a vector given as
$$x = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}$$
Can I claim that the product $x^TD^{-1}x$ can be given as 
$$x^TD^{-1}x = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}(x_1^Tx_1) + x_2^TA^{-1}x_2$$

It doesn't matter what I do afterwards. What matters is whether this is allowed.

Comment: Yes you can claim that. Why do you think that it is not allowed? $\epsilon \to 0$ but $\epsilon \ne 0$.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure. Because in a way I interchange limit and inverse.

Comment: Oops. I noticed it. You can't claim that $ x^TD^{-1}x = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}(x_1^Tx_1) + x_2^TA^{-1}x_2$ But you can claim: $ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}x^TD^{-1}x = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}(x_1^Tx_1) + x_2^TA^{-1}x_2$.

Comment: Thanks! Essentially this means that I have to start with $D=\begin{bmatrix}\epsilon I & 0\\0 & A\end{bmatrix}$ in my original formulation, then do all the derivations as if $\epsilon$ is not zero and take the limit in the very end.